# Validate column format in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV where some rows are parents and some are children, and I want to validate whether the format of the child rows are correct by adding a `Yes/No` value to a new column via a dataframe.

```
Type,ID,Ext_ID,Name
Parent,1111,abc.xyz.num1,yyy
Child,1,break://abc.xyz.num1/break1,break1
Child,2,break://abc.xyz.num1,break2
Parent,2222,abc.xyz.num2,zzz
Child,1,break://abc.xyz.num2/break1,break1
Child,2,break://abc.xyz.num2/break2,break2
Child,3,abc.xyz.num2/,break3
Child,4,break://abc.xyz.num2/break4,break4
Parent,3333,abc.xyz.num3,sss
Child,1,break://abc.xyz.num3/break1,break1
```

The *correct* format of the child `Ext_ID` is `break://abc.xyz.{Ext_ID of parent}/break{Name}`, so what would be the best way to achieve the desired output?

```
  Type    ID                         Ext_ID   Name  all_breaks_correct_format
Parent  1111                   abc.xyz.num1    yyy                         No
 Child     1    break://abc.xyz.num1/break1 break1  
 Child     2           break://abc.xyz.num1 break2  
Parent  2222                   abc.xyz.num2    zzz                         No
 Child     1    break://abc.xyz.num2/break1 break1  
 Child     2    break://abc.xyz.num2/break2 break2  
 Child     3                  abc.xyz.num2/ break3  
 Child     4    break://abc.xyz.num2/break4 break4  
Parent  3333                   abc.xyz.num3    sss                        Yes
 Child     1    break://abc.xyz.num3/break1 break1
```

Comment: Parent and Childs can be shuffled or they are already sorted?

Comment: is `{num}` the child `ID` column or it is any number?

Comment: @Corralien - already sorted

Comment: @SalvatoreDanieleBianco I updated the question to make it a little clearer. Note that I only care about the format of the `Child` rows and now `Parent`

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_csv("/content/sample_data/your_csv.csv")
df
```

Define a parents dataframe (simple part):

```
parents = df.loc[df.Type=="Parent"]
parents.index.name = "parent_id"


#    Type   ID  Ext_ID
#parent_id          
#0  Parent  1111    abc.xyz.num1
#3  Parent  2222    abc.xyz.num2
#8  Parent  3333    abc.xyz.num3
```

Define the children dataframe (difficult part):

```
children = pd.DataFrame(
    np.split(df.index, df.loc[df.Type=="Parent"].index)[1:],
    index=df.loc[df.Type=="Parent"].index
).iloc[:,1:].stack().astype(int).rename("child_id").reset_index()\
.set_index("child_id").level_0.rename("parent_id").to_frame().join(df)
```

Retrieve the Ext of parents for each child:

```
children = children.merge(
    parents.Ext_ID, left_on="parent_id", right_index=True,
    suffixes=["_child", "_parent"]
)
```

Check if the children Ext is correct:

```
children["expected_Ext_ID_child"] = "break://"+children.Ext_ID_parent+"/break"+children.ID.astype(str)
children["correct_Ext_ID"] = (children.Ext_ID_child==children.expected_Ext_ID_child)
```

`children` is:

```
    parent_id   Type    ID  Ext_ID_child    Ext_ID_parent   expected_Ext_ID_child   correct_Ext_ID
child_id                            
1   0   Child   1   break://abc.xyz.num1/break1 abc.xyz.num1    break://abc.xyz.num1/break1 True
2   0   Child   2   break://abc.xyz.num1    abc.xyz.num1    break://abc.xyz.num1/break2 False
4   3   Child   1   break://abc.xyz.num2/break1 abc.xyz.num2    break://abc.xyz.num2/break1 True
5   3   Child   2   break://abc.xyz.num2/break2 abc.xyz.num2    break://abc.xyz.num2/break2 True
6   3   Child   3   abc.xyz.num2/   abc.xyz.num2    break://abc.xyz.num2/break3 False
7   3   Child   4   break://abc.xyz.num2/break4 abc.xyz.num2    break://abc.xyz.num2/break4 True
9   8   Child   1   break://abc.xyz.num3/break1 abc.xyz.num3    break://abc.xyz.num3/break1 True
```

Finally:

```
parents["all_breaks_correct_format"] = parents.join(children.set_index("parent_id").correct_Ext_ID).groupby(axis=0, level=0).correct_Ext_ID.all()
df = df.join(parents.all_breaks_correct_format)
```

**PS**

Note that I assumed that `{num}` must equal `ID`.